# Django user profile form validation problem

Tags: django, forms, validation, profile

I'm trying to implement user profile module to my django project, but I'm getting this error:

```
Form 'SignupForm' could be validated, while 'ProfileForm' couldn't. Please make sure the two classes are compatible. Validation errors were: * user
  * Обязательное поле.(can't be blank)
```

My code:

http://pastie.org/2586199

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably just set the Model meta attribute to your profile class manually instead of grabbing it from the settings:

```
from some.module import MyProfile
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    pass

    class Meta:
        model = MyProfile
```

That code seems to be vastly over complicating a fairly simple operation